# Regular Expression lookahead / lookback for punctuation patterns

Tags: ruby, regex

Using Ruby, I want to find a regular expression that correctly identifies sentence boundaries, which I am defining as any string that ends in [.!?] except when these punctuation marks exist within quotation marks, as in

> My friend said "John isn't here!" and then he left.

My current code that is falling short is:

```
text = para.text.scan(/[^\.!?]+[(?<!(.?!)\"|.!?] /).map(&:strip)
```

I've pored over the regex docs, but still can't seem to understand lookbacks/lookaheads correctly.

Comment: Consider: "Jack's a good boy. I'm sure he is!`.  One sentence or two? Perhaps you should only be concerned with double quotes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good point. How would you go about tackling that, so as to keep each sentence clean? Am using Wikipedia as sources, and then extracting sentences to test kids on punctuation.

Comment: I don't see how you can determine sentence breaks where the terminator is between single quotes. Can you concern yourself only with double quotes?

Comment: Why not allow `'` to be in the sentence, only if its followed by an `s`such as `Jack's` or proceeded by an `s` such as `Charles'`. Would be fairly easy to define in regex.

Comment: @Lindrian, I'm not sure about that. Aren't there lots of cases where that wouldn't work? How 'bout ,"I once read a book called, 'Seven secrets. Seven lives'". (btw, "its followed"?)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: It's difficult to match it 100%, but for purposes of NLP parsing you can often get away with 'good enough'. If you wanted to parse it properly, you'd write out more extensive rules as to how things should look. I have done it before, gave me a ~90%+ correct match on my corpus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

`/(?:"(?>[^"]|\\.)+"|[a-z]\.[a-z]\.|[^.?!])+[!.?]/gi`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bJ8hM5/2

How it works:
The regex, will at each position in the string, check for the following

1. A quoted string in the form of "quote" which can contain *anything* up until the ending quote. You can also have escaped quotes, such as `"hell\"o"`.
2. Match any letter, followed by a dot, followed by another letter, and finally a dot. This is to match your special case of `U.S.` etc.
3. Match everything else that isn't a punctation character `.?!`.
4. Repeat up until we reach a punctation character.

Comment: Could you explain it please so that I can understand next time more clearly?

Comment: Also, in my real world text, there are occasional false positives generated by strings like 'U.S.' - if you could edit your answer to include not including this as well, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Sure, it has been adjusted.

Comment: I don't believe Ruby supports `/g`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Perhaps, but I'm sure OP knows how to use the expression. I don't even know if a global match is needed or not, just guessed.

Comment: I just tried your regex `r` with `/i` rather than `/gi` on `str` in my example: `str.scan(r)` works perfectly (except for whitespace at the beginning of sentences after the first, which is easily dealt with)! Excellent job!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial-regex solution that disregards sentence terminators that are contained between double-quotes.

**Code**

```
def extract_sentences(str, da_terminators)
  start_with_quote = (str[0] == '"')
  str.split(/(\".*?\")/)
     .flat_map.with_index { |b,i|
       (start_with_quote == i.even?) ? b : b.split(/([#{da_terminators}])/) }
     .slice_after(/^[#{da_terminators}]$/)
     .map { |sb| sb.join.strip }
 end
```

**Example**

```
puts extract_sentences(str, '!?.')
  # My friend said "John isn't here!", then "I'm outta' here" and then he left.
  # Let's go!
  # Later, he said "Aren't you coming?"
```

**Explanation**

For `str` above and

```
da_terminators = '!?.'
```

We will need the following later:

```
start_with_quote = (str[0] == '"')
  #=> false
```

Split the string on `"..."`. We need to make `\".*?\"` a capture group in order to keep it in the `split`. The result is an array, `block` that alternately has strings surrounded by double quotes and other strings. `start_with_quote` tells us which is which.

```
blocks = str.split(/(\".*?\")/)
  #=> ["My friend said ",
  #    "\"John isn't here!\"",
  #    ", then ",
  #    "\"I'm outta' here\"",
  #    " and then he left. Let's go! Later, he said ",
  #    "\"Aren't you coming?\""]
```

Split the string elements that are not surrounded by double quotes. The split is on any of the sentence terminating characters. Again it must be in a capture group in order to keep the separator.

```
new_blocks = blocks.flat_map.with_index { |b,i|
  (start_with_quote == i.even?) ? b : b.split(/([#{da_terminators}])/) }
  #=> ["My friend said ",
  #    "\"John isn't here!\"",
  #    ", then ",
  #    "\"I'm outta' here\"",
  #    " and then he left",
  #    ".",
  #    " Let's go",
  #    "!",
  #    " Later, he said ",
  #    "\"Aren't you coming?\""

sentence_blocks_enum = new_blocks.slice_after(/^[#{da_terminators}]$/)
  # #<Enumerator:0x007f9a3b853478>
```

Convert this enumerator to an array to see what it will pass into its block:

```
sentence_blocks_enum.to_a
  #=> [["My friend said ",
  #     "\"John isn't here!\"",
  #     ", then ",
  #     "\"I'm outta' here\"",
  #     " and then he left", "."],
  #    [" Let's go", "!"],
  #    [" Later, he said ", "\"Aren't you coming?\""]]
```

Combine the blocks of each sentence and `strip` whitespace, and return the array:

```
sentence_blocks_enum.map { |sb| sb.join.strip }
  #=> ["My friend said \"John isn't here!\", then \"I'm outta' here\" and then he left.",
  #    "Let's go!",
  #    "Later, he said \"Aren't you coming?\""]
```